isn't a proffer often a confession or a lead for the detectives?
When the bad guy is being interrogated and looking for immunity, and he says, "I'll tell you xYZ if you don't prosecute me," isn't that effectively telling the cops to investigate XYZ, even without his cooperation?
Like if he says, "I'll testify that Joey did the murder if you let me off," he just told the cops that Joey did the murder.
I guess I'm asking, how can you offer information without telling what the information is?

Not answering your question in practical terms, but in a tangential way that may be interesting: google "zero-knowledge proofs", which are cryptographic protocols that enable people to prove that they know something without disclosing what the "something" is.

I think he would more likely say "I'll tell you who did it" -- he won't give the name until after they grant immunity. And the immunity offer will likely be predicated on the information being true.

If you watch shows like "Law & Order", that's how it usually goes during the interrogation.

The police actually need two things, information and admissible evidence. Often they have more information than admissible evidence in a case, or on a suspect. Sufficiently credible information can help with further investigation while only evidence leads to conviction. Of course credible information may help to develop more admissible evidence.

Alice the mobster offers to testify that Bob the mobster killed Charlie the mobster.
Well, the police might already have had their strong suspicions that Bob did the hit. What Alice said might reinforce those suspicions, but that's not enough in court unless Alice actually testifies that Bob is the killer. If the police testify about Alice's statement, that would be hearsay.
Alice the mobster offers to testify that Bob the mobster killed Charlie the mobster and buried him in his back yard.
Even if Alice does not testify in court after all, this might be enough to get a search warrant for Bob's back yard and to look for bodies. If they find Charlie, and Bob's DNA under Charlie's fingernails, that might be the beginning of a case.
Alice the drug runner offers to testify that Bob the drug runner imported 200 pounds on April 1st of last year.
The police might already have had their strong suspicions that Bob is importing drugs. But if they go to court, and Alice simply refuses to testify because she might implicate herself, they will not be able to pin the case on Bob. The drugs are all sold, the money is laundered.

Rules for hearsay are complex and vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. But usually people can only testify about what they can personally swear to, and the police can only swear that Alice said something. Not that she was truthful.
